# Is it possible to use Istio without kubernetes or docker?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I have 4 microservices running on my laptop listening at various ports. Can I use Istio to create a service mesh on my laptop so the services can communicate with each other through Istio? All the links on google about Istio include kubernetes but I want to run Istio without Kubernetes. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In practice, not really as of this writing, since pretty much all the Istio runbooks and guides are available for Kubernetes.

In theory, yes. Istio components are designed to be ['platform independent'](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#security). Quote from the docs:

> While Istio is platform independent, using it with Kubernetes (or infrastructure) network policies, the benefits are even greater, including the ability to secure pod-to-pod or service-to-service communication at the network and application layers.

But unless you know really well the details of each of the components: [Envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/), [Mixer](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#mixer), [Pilot](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#pilot), [Citadel](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#citadel), and [Galley](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#galley) and you are willing to spend a lot of time it becomes not practically feasible to get it running outside of Kubernetes.

If you want to use something less tied to Kubernetes you can take a look at [Consul](https://www.consul.io/), although it doesn't have all the functionality Istio has, it has overlap with some of its features.

Answer (score 3):

I do some googles, and found that istio claim to support apps running outside k8s, like in vm. But I never try.

https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/0.x/announcing-0.2/#cross-environment-support

https://jimmysong.io/blog/istio-vm-odysssey/